# Only show columns in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have a plugin which by default shows extra columns in all columns, not only in that post type.
How do I change this code to only show up on this specific plugin page/post type?

```
function modified_column_register( $columns ) {
$columns['time_range'] = __( 'Display', 'vs' );
$columns['active'] = __('Active', 'vs');
return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'modified_column_register' );
```

Thank you! I tried adding this without any luck:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
if  ( 'visitors' == $screen->post_type ) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Changed to manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns and that made it work!